# What are the Pros and Cons of Cascading delete and updates?

Tags: sql-server-2008, cascade, cascading-deletes

Maybe this is sort of a naive question...but I think that we should always have cascading deletes and updates. But I wanted to know are there problems with it and when should we should  not do it? I really can't think of a case right now where you would not want to do an cascade delete but I am sure there is one...but what about updates should they be done always?

So can anyone please list out the pros and cons of cascading deletes and updates ? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pros:

- When you delete a row from the Parent table all the foreign key rows are deleted
- This is usually faster than implementing this with triggers
- Orphaned rows are unlikely

Cons

- Orphans are possible
- If by mistake you delete a row in the parent table all the rows in the corresponding child    tables will be deleted and it will be PITA to figure out what you deleted

Answer (score 12):

This depends on the entities that are contained in the tables: if the side of the foreign key cannot exist without the side of the primary key, it makes sense to have cascaded delete.

E. g.: An invoice line item does not have any right to survive if the invoice is deleted.

But if you have a foreign key used for the relationship "works for" for the relationship between an employee and his/her boss, would you want to delete the employee if the boss leaves the company?

In addition: a technical issue is that some ORM (object relational mapping) tools are confused if dependent table entries change without them being responsible for that.

Comment: I am not sure that I would delete the boss exactly for this reason, I would probably inactivate the row

Comment: @SQLMenace Would you keep all former employees forever in an employee table?
But I hope you see the point: There are situations where the child has an existence by itself, even if the parent gets deleted.

Comment: I am not knocking on your answer, just saying what I would do..we record all changes anyhow and they go into a History table..depending on the company policy you might not be allowed to ever delete rows either

Comment: @SQLMenance If you are not allowed to delete data, then of course a cascaded delete does not make sense at all, and the setting cascade/restrict/set null is irrelevant anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Pros:

- Data integrity - Can help avoid situations where a record refers to something that is no longer there.

Cons:

- Performance - Cascading deletes/updates can be sloooooooooooooooooooow.
- Complexity - It seems most people I work with are not used to cascades, so when you give them a new project that has it, they're a bit surprised the first time they trigger one of these cascades.
- As others have already mentioned, can really mess things up when used improperly.

Comment: Or, in standard form, SLW O20

Comment: Your point about performance doesn't make sense. Cascading deletes/updates manually is slower than letting the database handle it.