# What are the cons of cascading deletes on the database?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the Pros and Cons of Cascading delete and updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578975/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-cascading-delete-and-updates)

What makes cascading deletes on the database (not via EF) a bad practice, according to some? The architect on this project refuses to consider using them and doesn't have time to discuss it.

I'm aware of the advantages of cascading deletes but would really like to hear about the negatives. Let's not turn this into a "work somewhere else" or "kidnap the architect and force him to explain why they're bad" bunch of replies :-)

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you run object logic (I.e. normal business objects) then cascading deletes mean objects don't run code, so objects can not do other things or object to being deleted (because it would be illegal from a business logic point of view at this moment).

Depending on architecture this can be really really bad.