# How to delete Category and SubCateogries?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I have little Confusion that when we delete Category is it necessary to delete Subcategory related to that if so please help by writing Sql query?Similarly if delete subcategory then deleting Category will also should be deleted as well?

```
+-------+------------+
| CatID |  CatName   |
+-------+------------+
|     1 | Seeds      |
|     2 | Pesticides |
|     3 | Fertilizer |
+-------+------------+

+----------+---------------+-----------+
| SubCatID |  SubCatName   |    CatID  |
+----------+---------------+-----------+
|        1 | Red Seed      |         1 |
|        2 | Red Seed      |         1 |
|        3 | Red Seed      |         1 |
|        4 | Red Seed      |         1 |
|        5 | National Worm |         2 |
+----------+---------------+-----------+
```

Comment: What have you already tried? What do you think is a possible answer? Have you researched "foreign key relationships" and "deleting a record"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL foreign key constraints, cascade delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914936/mysql-foreign-key-constraints-cascade-delete)

Comment: Are you sure you want to delete a category (and leave subcategories orphaned) when a *subcategory* is deleted? Maybe you meant when a category's *last* subcategory is deleted? Even then I don't know if I would make that automatic. You have some suggestions for `CASCADE` but I generally [steer people away from that option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578975/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-cascading-delete-and-updates). For a relationship this simple it is quite easy to encapsulate this logic in a single, easy-to-debug stored procedure to handle category and/or subcategory deletes.

Comment: @Thomas MySQL and SQL Server are not the same.

Comment: @AaronBertrand sure. But the idea of a cascading delete is pretty universal.

Comment: @Thomas Doesn't make it a good duplicate. The answers have syntax *this OP can't use*.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks I have applied the cascading logic and its working.

Comment: @AaronBertrand fair.

Answer (score 1):

Given you have a `Foreign Key` defined on this relation, then yes, you have to delete (because childs cannot be orphans) or set null (if you column CatId allows `null` values) on the `CatID` column on the `Subcategories` table because the relational databases uses the `referential integrity`. You can define the `CASCADE` option to do it for you automatically.

```
ALTER TABLE SubCategory
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SubCategory_Category
    FOREIGN KEY (CatId)
    REFERENCES Category (CatId)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Check [this article](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php) for more details.

If you have a FK and want more control what you are deleting, you must provide two sql statements to make it, for sample.

```
delete from subcategory where catId = 1
delete from category where catId = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `ON DELETE CASCADE` by altering current schema :

```
ALTER TABLE SubCategory
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_SubCat_CatID FOREIGN KEY (CatID) REFERENCES category(CatID )
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

By this when you delete category from `category` table, the reference data would auto delete. Just make sure drop your current constraint before create new one with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.